# Whitelabel Error Page There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404, whenever i return an HTML page from @requestMapping Controller,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, http-status-code-404

https://github.com/hardikSinghBehl/jokes-app

[The Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYGaZ.png)

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hardik</groupId>
    <artifactId>chuck-norris-jokes-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring-Boot-chuck-norris-jokes-app</name>
    <description>Project using spring boot and actuator to create a jokes application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>   
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>chuck-norris-for-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Controller class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.hardik.chucknorrisjokesapp.services.JokeService;

@Controller
public class JokeController {
    private JokeService jokeService;

    public JokeController() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    public JokeController(JokeService jokeService) {
        super();
        this.jokeService = jokeService;
    }

    @RequestMapping({"/",""})
    public String showJoke(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("joke", jokeService.getJoke());
        return "chucknorris";
    }
}
```

Service class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import guru.springframework.norris.chuck.ChuckNorrisQuotes;

@Service
public class ChuckNorrisJokeService implements JokeService{
    private ChuckNorrisQuotes chuckNorrisQuotes;


    public ChuckNorrisJokeService() {
        super();
        this.chuckNorrisQuotes = new ChuckNorrisQuotes();
    }

    public ChuckNorrisJokeService(ChuckNorrisQuotes chuckNorrisQuotes) {
        super();
        this.chuckNorrisQuotes = chuckNorrisQuotes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getJoke(){
        return chuckNorrisQuotes.getRandomQuote();
    }
}
```

code works fine, i don't get any error, but when i go to localhost, the 404 error message is displayed
ChuckNorrisQuotes class is available in jar file added in dependencies

have attatched my git repository for this project, have tried everything and i am stuck, tried getMapping annotation, tried @getParam

when i am using @RestComponent, then local host is returning "chucknorris" as a String on screen rather than the html file in resources/templates

Comment: Can you add `/` to *return "chucknorris";* and make it as `return "/chucknorris";` and have a try again

Comment: tried it, didn't work

Comment: I think everything is good check https://github.com/hardikSinghBehl/jokes-app/pull/1